# wp_link_pages appearing after post content and not at bottom of page

Tags: wp-link-pages

This code worked perfectly! But my issues is that it removes text on pages. I just need the page numbering to appear immediately after the post and not at the bottom of the page. Any suggestions?

```
add_filter ('the_content', 'pagination_after_post',1);
function pagination_after_post($content) {
   if(is_single()) {
      $content.= '<div class="pagination">' . wp_link_pages('before=&after=&next_or_number=next&nextpagelink=Next&previouspagelink=Previous') . '</div>';
   }
   return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call of `wp_link_pages` displays navigation immediately because `echo` argument is set to `1` by default, and it means to echo result. So try to add `&echo=0` at the ennd of `wp_link_pages` call:

```
add_filter ('the_content', 'pagination_after_post',1);
function pagination_after_post($content) {
   if(is_single()) {
      $content.= '<div class="pagination">' . wp_link_pages('before=&after=&next_or_number=next&nextpagelink=Next&previouspagelink=Previous&echo=0') . '</div>';
   }
   return $content;
}
```

Read more about `wp_link_pages` parameters in [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages#Parameters).

Comment: Awesome but now it removes all of the text from my pages after adding this code to function.php any suggestions....

Comment: It's working now! I misplaced a quotation mark. Thanks so much!